# Read lists and dicts from file without exec

Tags: python, io, exec, unsafe

Currently I have this code, which reads from a file containing something similar to `[{'1': {'Score': '2', 'Class': '3'}}]` and assigns it to a variable:

```
exec('assigns = ' + open(r'D:\Dropbox\Dev\Output\dict', 'r').read())
```

However, I have been told that using `exec` is dangerous. How can I write the same code without using `exec`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
assigns = ast.literal_eval(open(r'D:\Dropbox\Dev\Output\dict', 'r').read())
```

It will only evaluate literals, no function calls or operators.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> data = """[{'1': {'Score': '2', 'Class': '3'}}]""" # example; get this from file
>>> import ast
>>> x = ast.literal_eval(data)
>>> x[0]
{'1': {'Score': '2', 'Class': '3'}}
>>> x[0]['1']
{'Score': '2', 'Class': '3'}
>>> x[0]['1']['Class']
'3'
>>>
```